# Vue-Router Data Fetch: Fetch Data before 'beforeRouteUpdate' loads component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, axios, vuex, vue-router

I am new to vue-router navigation guards and so I recently realized that I needed to use `beforeRouteUpdate` guard for reused components where for example: Going from `/foo/1` to `/foo/2`

However, while coming to `/foo/1`, I pulled data from database through an axios call and before going to `/foo/2`, I need to pull new data again through the axios call.

This is where I face a problem where the navigation guard `beforeRouteUpdate` loads the component `/foo/2` before my data loads from the axios call and thus I get null in a few of my variables.

How can I make `beforeRouteUpdate` wait to load the next component so that all my data is loaded from the axios calls?

As for my code, it looks like this:

```
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    Vue.set(this.$store.state.user, 'get_user', null)
    this.$store.dispatch(OTHER_PROFILE_GET, to.params.id).then(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
      if(this.$store.getters.is_user_loaded) {

        next()

      } else {

        this.$store.watch((state, getters) => getters.is_user_loaded, () => 
        {
          if(this.$store.getters.is_user_loaded) {
            console.log(this.$store.state.user.get_user);
            console.log('comes here');
            next()
          }
        })
      }
    })
},
```

To explain my code further, I have called this method in my component and so I when I go from `/user/1` to `/user/2` I dispatch a Vuex action which makes an axios call to get the new profile details but before the axios call completes and loads the data in the Vuex state, the `beforeRouteUpdate` already loads the next component.

Comment: What does your code look like? Have you followed [the official guide](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation)?

Comment: I have updates my question with my code. As for the official guide, I have gone through that and other examples of beforeRouteUpdate to understand its proper use but wasn't able to solve the problem @Phil

Comment: Don't forget to hit that _"Save Edits"_ button when editing your question

Comment: Sorry my bad. I updated the question after commenting @Phil

Comment: You should only update state through a mutation, not directly (via `Vue.set` or otherwise)

Comment: Yes for sure. That `Vue.set` was mainly as a test. But everything other state update is through a mutation in Vuex

Comment: What does your `is_user_loaded` getter do? What does `user.get_user` represent? Presumably your component relies on store data; what and how is it using from the store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your action should perform any state mutation such as setting `user.get_user` to `null`. I'm also not sure why you've added a *watch*; your action should only resolve when complete. For example

```js
actions: {
  [OTHER_PROFILE_GET] ({ commit }, id) {
    commit('clearUserGetUser') // sets state.user.get_user to null or something
    return axios.get(`/some/other/profile/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`).then(res => {
      commit('setSomeStateData', res.data) // mutate whatever needs to be set
    })
  }
}
```

then your route guard should have something like

```js
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
  this.$store.dispatch(OTHER_PROFILE_GET, to.params.id).then(next)
}
```

---

In order to prevent errors from trying to render `null` data, use your getters. For example, say your getter is

```
getters: {
  is_user_loaded (state) {
    return !!state.user.get_user
  }
}
```

in your component, you can map this to a computed property...

```
computed: {
  isUserLoaded () {
    return this.$store.getters.is_user_loaded // or use the mapGetters helper
  },
  user () {
    return this.$store.state.user.get_user // or use the mapState helper
  }
}
```

then in your template, use this logic to conditionally render some data

```
<div v-if="isUserLoaded">
  Hello {{user}}
</div>
<div v-else>
  Loading...
</div>
```

This is the suggested approach in the [vue-router guide for `beforeRouteUpdate`](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation)

Comment: I tried this method but it failed to fetch the data before the `beforeRouteUpdate` loaded the next component. My getters, however, are getting a boolean to check if the profile is loaded into the `store.state` or if its null. To my understanding, `beforeRouteUpdate` doesn't reload the component and so while reusing the component, when the data in `state` change it reacts to changing the existing variables in the component and when data is null it gives an error

Comment: @pk_45 sounds like you need some presentation logic in your template then to not attempt to render the data if it's `null`. I'll add an example

Comment: @pk_45 it also sounds like your action isn't resolving only after your data has been retrieved. Are you forgetting to `return` the axios promise (see my example above)?

Comment: Hey so after understanding and implementing your method I was able to figure it out. Thanks for all the help. I mainly used your method to see that it is not null before I load the data and it worked. @Phil

Comment: Do you mind explaining why do you use `[OTHER_PROFILE_GET]` - I mean, do you use dynamic object keys?

Comment: @jean see https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#using-constants-for-mutation-types

Comment: @Phil looks interesting - out of curiosity: would you be able to provide real life example of using it? I'm not sure where to use it and how that would improve code beside taking advantage of tooling

Comment: @jeand'arme I don't typically use them but the person asking this question does so that's why it's in my answer. For a more general answer, see [What is wrong with magic strings?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365339/what-is-wrong-with-magic-strings)